# In Magento, what does a controller typically do?

Tags: magento, controller

I have seen some basic examples of controllers where, in their indexAction() method, they do something like echo 'This is an index action'. But in real applications, would that method return a long string of html, starting with <html>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you've seen are just to show you that code in the controller is executing. What you're supposed to do in a Magento controller is

1. Manipulate models based on values from the request (get, post, etc.)
2. Tell Magento to load and render the layout that will make up the response

The layout/block system reads directly from the system model classes, so there's no need to do anything output related in the controller (that's not 100% true, but if you know the reasons it's not 100% true you didn't need to read this far in the answer)

If you look at Magento Core controllers, you'll most of them ends with

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

These are the lines that start output.  No `echo` required.

Comment: thanks for your answer, helpful as always. I find it a question of programmer preference whether the Model manipulation should be performed in the Controller or the Block. There's no doubt the access control and execution of business logic belong in the controller (IMHO) but things like loading, paging, sorting, filtering Model data is usually performed in the Block.  It is, however, a grey line.  Can you expand your answer to address this grey line?

Comment: Thank you. Any chance you could explain what layout the call to loadLayout loads? There is so much information out there, but no one good resource. Can a custom module only have one layout or can it have several? Where should it/they be defined? In config.xml I guess, but in adminhtml section or frontend section? And where do the layout files live on the file system? I've been searching around for a decent article explaining this concisely, but no luck.

Comment: @user I've spent the last 3 years explaining that. Start with Magento for MVC developers. http://alanstorm.com/category/magento  Then buy this book http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

Comment: @Jonathan Magento Inc. itself handles the grey line differently in different areas of the system, so I'm not sure there's much canonical to say there.   Develop your own internal guidelines, follow them, and re-factor as you discover what works for you and your team.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, most controllers use XML layouts to generate a series of logical blocks that should be displayed on the page, and then render those blocks recursively to build the page. Note that they do not actually return that string, and the layout classes are responsible for getting the output into the right place. This is the code you'll usually see for this case:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
```

Using echo is a quick shorthand that lets the developer ignore the entire layout system temporarily and just focus on triggering the correct action.

Hope that clears things up a bit!

Thanks,
Joe